# check string in array for special characters

Tags: php, arrays, special-characters

I have got an array wich contains several strings like this:

```
array(133) {
 [0]=>
  array(1) {
["row"]=>
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(10) "testd ' /% ata"
  [1]=>
  string(14) "testdata 111"
  [2]=>
  string(17) "testdata 123"
  [3]=>
  string(0) ""
  [4]=>
  string(0) ""
 }
}
[1]=>
 array(1) {
 ["row"]=>
 array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(9) "198"
  [1]=>
  string(14) "testdata"
  [2]=>
  string(41) "testdat"
  [3]=>
  string(0) ""
  [4]=>
  string(0) ""
 }
}
```

My question is how can I check the strings within the array on special chars? These special chars are causing a syntax error when importing into my DB.

I think i need to use something like this?

```
preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_ -%][().][\/]/s', '', $String);
```

Can anyone help me on this one?

Allright nog i have created this piece of code:

```
        // search for special chars in the import data and remove them 
        $illegal = "#$%^&*()+=-[]';,./{}|:<>?~";

        foreach ($data_set as $data) 
        foreach ($data_set['data'] as $row) {
           if(strpbrk($row, $illegal)) {
            echo($row);
            die();
           }                
            else {
                //not allowed ,escape or do what you want
                echo("no characters found");
                die();
            } 
            var_dump($row);
            die();
         }
```

But this still gives an error:

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message:  strpbrk() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Filename: controllers/import.php

Line Number: 153

no characters found

Comment: Are you escaping it when inserting it to your database? You may be trying to solve the wrong problem.

Comment: use prepared statement with placeholder

Comment: To check strings.. and then what? Strip those symbols from string? Delete those strings from array? Or even delete whole array item with them?

Comment: use mysql_real_escapse_string() function to escape \,'," chars

Comment: Allright, i might be still a newbe on this one. The ' is causing a syntax error and I want to prevent to have this error. I thought removing the special chars from the strings in my array would solve this problem.

Comment: @Alma Do Mundo - the purpose is to strip those symbols from the string

Comment: See http://kunststube.net/escapism.

Comment: Search for `strpbrk()`

Comment: @FaceOfJock I have tried you code but still get an error. See my comments in the question. You know why?

Answer (score 0):

You may have a look at [`strpbrk`](http://php.net/strpbrk). It should solve your problem.

Example:

```
$tests = "testd ' /% ata";
);
$illegal = "#$%^&*()+=-[]';,./{}|:<>?~";

echo (false === strpbrk($test, $illegal)) ? 'Allowed' : "Contains special chars";
```

But i suggest to **escape** your strings before inserting to database,it's much safer.

```
foreach ($yourArray as $array) 
foreach ($array['row'] as $row) {

    if(strpbrk($row, $illegal)) { 
         //allowed ,insert to db
    }
    else {
        //not allowed ,escape or do what you want
    }  

 }
```

Comment: how do I apply this one to an array? My array is in the variable $data_set